# Django production - No db table load in admin

Tags: python, django, admin

I'm building a Django app and now I'm in production. I have this problem: after performing manage.py syncdb (all it's ok) I go into admin and I can not find the models tables . My admin.py file is present and this is my file url.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'stambol.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^stambol/', include('stambol.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "can not find the models tables"? Does it work locally? How is your production environment different from your development environment (maybe nginx vs. runserver)?

Comment: When I enter in admin pannel I found only the auth, site and group models. I don't find other models (in my models.py I have a lot of models). Locally it's work well. I think that I don't know how to restart the server in production...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Permissions**

First off, make sure you have permission to edit the missing models. It's common to be developing with a superuser account, and then to test your production deployment with a different non-superuser account. If you don't have at least read permission, the class won't be listed at all in the admin.

I think this is the most likely cause, but I will leave the rest since I had already written it.

**Discovering your admin registrations:**

One notable difference between runserver and a production server is that when you run `runserver`, it imports all your `models.py` files and validates the models. This does not happen in production, so if you register your models with the admin inside `models.py` you need to be sure to import that file so that code runs. You could do so in your main url conf.

The preferable solution is to do your registration in per-app `admin.py` files so they are picked up by `autodiscover`.

**Settings:**

You do need admin listed in installed apps, as @Pratik says. It also has some dependencies, as mentioned [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overview). Installed apps should contain at least this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.auth', 
    'django.contrib.contenttypes', 
    'django.contrib.sessions'
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    #...
    'myapp',
    #...
]
```

Make sure the dir containing your app `myapp` is in your python path, so that `myapp` is picked up by `autodiscover`. This is working correctly for you already, or else you would get something like `ImportError: No module named myapp`.

**Restarting the server:**

Finally, just to recap what is buried deep within comments, you can restart your production server after making any code changes by touching your wsgi file: `touch wsgi.py`. Use tab-completion when you do this to be sure you're touching the existing wsgi file and not creating a new one thanks to a typo or some such.  The wsgi file you're touching should contain something like this:

```
...

# tell django to find settings at APPS_DIR/mainsite/settings.py'
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mainsite.settings'

# hand off to the wsgi application
application = WSGIHandler()
```

**Still broken?**

If things still aren't working as expected, think farther outside the box. Keeping in mind that you're new to your production environment, is it possible some other code besides your own is being served up? Make some obvious change to a front-end page, restart the server, and see if it works. This is just a shot in the dark, of course.

Comment: thank you very much @dokkaebi, I followed step by step your suggestions and something work! Now I have this situation: when I restart with touch wsgi.py I have an error "ImportError: No module named..". I have installed the module bat I must learning how to setup the PYTHONPATH..

Answer (score 0):

```
from django import admin
from example.models import YourModel

admin.site.register(YourModel) 
# or

class ModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(YourModel, YourModelAdmin)
```

This should do the trick

Comment: I have this in my admin.py. I have admin.site.register(mymodel) for all the models...

Comment: Have you added this app to installed app? Have you restarted the server after adding admin.py file?

Comment: Yes the app is in "installed app". I don't know how restart the server. Sorry bat it's the first time for me in production...

Comment: If it's in production usually you restart server by using command: touch site.wsgi (or other name for your production wsgi file). If it's served locally - you just rerun manage.py runserver

Comment: something like this?  "/dirmyproject/myproject$ touch myproject.wsgi"(in this directory there is wsgi.py...)

Comment: I did this command. It created the file myproject.wsgi. The admin is however unchanged.

Comment: you cd into your project dir and then;
touch myproject.wsgi
or 
touch project_path/myproject.wsgi

Comment: @RoverDar you should remove the `myproject.wsgi` file that you created by touching. Instead, you should `touch wsgi.py`. The point is that your server will restart if the modified date on that file (it should have code in it!) is newer than when the server started. I always use tab-completion when touching wsgi.py to avoid accidentally creating something with the wrong name or in the wrong directory.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the below removed as comments inside `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`. Then run `./manage.py syncdb` again. They should like as shown below without the `#` in front of them

```
   # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
     'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
     'django.contrib.admindocs',
```

Comment: In INSTALLED_APPS 'django.contrib.admin' and 'django.contrib.admindocs" are commented out..

Comment: You have to un-comment them i.e they should be installed.